# Get exact position of string in a file- UNIX command line

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I'm looking for some strings in a file and I need their exact position (line number and position in the line) using UNIX commands.

I'm only able to find line numbers using ***grep -n***, but I can't get number of appearance or even their positions.

I know how to write a script in R using ***gregexpr*** function to do all this, but I would like to use only UNIX commands. Is there some equivalent for it?

Comment: Don't assume that the people reading this have any clue what `gregexpr` is. Tell us explicitly what you want rather than saying you want a solution equivalent to something that we've never heard of. Also, post some sample input ad expected output.

Answer (score 2):

For getting line number and all positions of a pattern on a line you can use this awk command:

```
cat file
#This is your hosts file
127.0.0.1 localhost linux 
192.168.1.2 domain1.com 
#this is added automatically to 
192.168.1.2 sub.domain1.com www.domain1.com
```

---

```
awk -v p='domain1' 'index($0,p) {
   printf "%s:", NR;
   s=$0; m=0;
   while((n=index(s, p))>0) {
      m+=n;
      printf "%s ", m;
      s=substr(s, n+1)
   }
   print ""
}' file
3:13 
5:17 33
```

---

Following alternate awk command should also work:

```
awk -v p='domain1' 'index($0,p) {
   printf "%s:", NR;
   l=length(p);
   s=$0;
   m=0;
   while((n=index(s, p))>0) {
      m = m ? m+n+l-1 : m+n;
      printf "%s ", m;
      s=substr(s, n+l)
   }
   print ""
}' file
3:13 
5:17 33
```

Comment: @EdMorton: I provided a better example and reformatted the awk command to make it verbose. Through this awk I tried to list `line #:` followed by all the starting positions of the pattern on that line. Not sure whether OP really wants this much info.

Comment: Beats me, I just noticed the formatting of your script was tough to read and that you say `using grep` in your intro line and then don't use grep. Not sure I fully understand your script (it looks longer than I'd expect but maybe that's necessary, idk), but at a glance you should change `$0 ~ p` to `index($0,p)`.

Comment: Thanks so much @EdMorton. Yes grep was a silly typo and I replaced `$0 ~ p` by `index($0,p)` and shortened the script by removing use of array.

Comment: You inspired me to write a script that does the same thing. Theres some interesting differences between our approaches, the most notable being that you advance the string past the first character of the matched word while I advance it beyond the whole of the matched word. I wonder if there's any functional difference as a result of that. I need to think about that for a bit!

Comment: With little further logic I can make it advance by length of the needle. See edit.

Comment: I don't think you need to. I've convinced myself that advancing one char is sufficient for strings with index(), it just wouldn't work for REs with match(). I wouldn't use the letter `l` (el) as a variable name, though, as it looks far too much like the number `1` (one).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
now is
the winter of our
discontent

$ awk 's=index($0,"winter") { print "line=" NR, "start position=" s}' file
line=2 start position=5
```

If you'd like to find all occurrences of the string:

```
$ cat file
now is
the winter (yes, winter) of our
discontent

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ SLENGTH = length(string) }
{
    skipped = 0
    starts = ""
    while ( SSTART = index($0,string) ) {
        starts = starts (starts?" ":"") (skipped + SSTART)
        $0 = substr($0,SSTART + SLENGTH)
        skipped += (SSTART + SLENGTH - 1)
    }
}
starts { print "line=" NR, "start position(s)=" starts }

$ awk -v string="winter" -f tst.awk file
line=2 start position(s)=5 18
```

I wouldn't normally advocate the use of all-upper-case variable names since those usually indicate built-in variables but in this case I want to clearly show the equivalence between index() for strings (user-provided SSTART/SLENGTH) and match() for regexps (built-in RSTART/RLENGTH).

IMHO SSTART/SLENGTH should have been built into the index() function but I understand why they weren't (functionally unnecessary, unlike RLENGTH for match(), and so unnecessary performance impact) and I doubt if that will happen at this point so it's nbd. Here's a version that defines and uses an index() function (names `sidx()`) to do that if anyone cares/prefers:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function sidx(src,tgt) {
    SLENGTH = ( (SSTART=index(src,tgt)) ? length(tgt) : 0 )
    return SSTART
}
{
    skipped = 0
    starts = ""
    while ( sidx($0,string) ) {
        starts = starts (starts?" ":"") skipped + SSTART
        $0 = substr($0,SSTART + SLENGTH)
        skipped += SSTART + SLENGTH - 1
    }
}
starts { print "line=" NR, "start position(s)=" starts }
$
$ awk -v string="winter" -f tst.awk file
line=2 start position(s)=5 18
```

Warning: the above scripts will go into an infinite loop if you pass in an empty string as the string to be searched for. You can add a test for that in the BEGIN section if you care.

If you'd like something different, update your question with some sample input and expected output and clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact position in a line like this:

echo "Unix forum is the best site." | grep -o "[-_a-zA-Z0-9.]" | grep -n x

4:x

I found here: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/26190-finding-character-position-file.html

And you can combine it with your solution.

(Ehh. It works only for characters...)

Comment: That functionality is more simply, robustly, and efficiently implemented by `echo "Unix forum is the best site." | awk '{print index($0,"x")}'` which will also work for any strings, not just some characters. Turns out Unix forum may not be the best site :-).